# Which APIs trigger "app would like to control this computer using accessibility features"?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've noticed that on newer macOS versions my app suddenly shows this security warning:

[image: screenshot]

(screenshot taken from [here](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus/issues/107) because my system is in German)

Now I'm wondering why macOS is showing this. I don't remember using any accessibility features but of course I must be using some because otherwise this security warning would not appear. I've checked my code and I'm not using any features from `NSAccessibility`. But since I get this warning, there must be other calls that trigger it as well. But how to find them?

That's why I'd like to ask how I can find out what Cocoa APIs are actually causing this security warning to appear? What should I look for? Is there a list of functions/classes that trigger this warning?

Note that I'm not using Xcode but I'm building my app in a very old-fashioned way using a set of makefiles.

Comment: Are you using system events? AppleScript? Come on, give us a clue what your “app” does. Also did you try watching any recent WWDC mac security videos? This stuff is well explained.

Comment: It's a cross-platform programming language available for a wide range of systems so it does lots of stuff but the macOS backend is rather small. Of course, I could go through the macOS backend and disable stuff one by one to see what's causing it but of course I'd like to avoid this rather tedious route. I'm not using system events or AppleScript. I haven't watched any WWDC videos.

Comment: Do you use functions like `AXIsProcessTrusted` or `AXUIElementCreateApplication`?

Comment: @Willeke: No, I don't.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question: what APIs trigger this panel?  Upvoted to compensate for someone else's arbitrary downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a complete answer to the question but at least I've found out the culprit now. I had some code in there that allowed the user to programmatically move the mouse cursor. Disabling this code made the warning go away. The code looks like this:

```
CGPoint p;
CGEventRef me;

p.x = x;
p.y = y;

if(!(me = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, p, 0))) return;

CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, me);
CFRelease(me);
```