# Is it possible to get fine-tuned control over security warnings?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My app uses the following code to programmatically move the mouse cursor:

```
void movecursor(int x, int y) {

   CGPoint p;
   CGEventRef me;

   p.x = x;
   p.y = y;

   if(!(me = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, p, 0))) return;

   CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, me);
   CFRelease(me);
}
```

Now I've [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59345237/1197719) that having this code inside an executable will automatically trigger the following security warning on macOS >= 10.14:

[image: screenshot]

(screenshot taken from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppGJ2.png) because my system is in German)

Now my problem is this: The code I posted above is hardly ever used by my app. In fact, my app is an interpreted programming language and it offers a call named `MoveCursor` to allow scripts to move the mouse cursor. However, 99.9% of the scripts never actually call it. But still, having the code inside my app executable seems to be enough to trigger the security warning.

So is there a way to suppress this security warning and make macOS only show it when the code presented above is actually called? Or is there a way to tell macOS to not show this warning and have my app manually ask for permission when it needs to actually execute the code?

That would be much better for my app because as it stands, 99.9% of the users will never ever use this code but currently its presence in the app executable seems to be enough to trigger the warning. It'd really be better to have some more fine-tuned control over those security warnings. Is that possible?

Comment: "But still, having the code inside my app executable seems to be enough to trigger the security warning" > This is not correct; either `CGEventPost` or some other code path is triggering the accessibility prompt when it's run.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're absolutely right. I missed an instance that indeed called `CGEventPost` so it made perfect sense for macOS to show this security warning. However, I still get a warning from the notification center whenever starting an app for the first time. I've tried to disable `NSBeep` and also all references to `NSUserNotificationCenter` but I still get the warning. Could it be that the notification center warning is shown for all apps, no matter if they actually show notifications or not?

Comment: A quick test showed me that, no, the prompt is not shown for a new, empty app. Adding a call to `deliverNotification:` caused the prompt to be shown when that code was run. So I think interaction with the notification API is required to trigger the prompt. Note that on 10.14+, the new UserNotifications framework gives more fine-grained control over requesting permissions.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that in my initialization code I was doing `[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];` and this was triggering the permission request from the notification center.